# Stretching element to contain all children

Tags: qt, qml

How is it possible in [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) to automatically stretch element so that all its childs fit in it? And how to specify spacing? For example, I would like to have a rectangle around a text. The rectangle should have some internal spacing.

If I write the following then the rectangle has a size of 0,0.

```
Rectangle {
    color: "gray"
    anchors.centerIn: parent;

    Text {
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

If I try to fix it by using the `Column` element, as suggested in *[How to make QML items to grow to fit contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807557/how-to-make-qml-items-to-grow-to-fit-contents)*, then I get a column through the whole window/parent,

```
Column {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Rectangle {
        color: "gray"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I have also tried to use the `Flow` element instead of `Column`, but then I got a row through the whole window/parent.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [`childrenRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childrenRect-prop) property for this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 200

    Rectangle {
        color: "BurlyWood"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: childrenRect.width + 20
        height: childrenRect.height + 20

        Text {
            id: hello
            x: 10
            y: 10
            text: "Hello"
        }

        Text {
            anchors.left: hello.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.top: hello.top
            text: "World"
        }
    }
}
```

However, note that using `childrenRect` in combination with using `anchors.centerIn: parent` in one of the direct children yields a warning about a binding loop.

Comment: `main.qml:6: ReferenceError: childrenRect is not defined`. What is the problem? Qt 5.3, QtQuick 2.3

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Hmm, I can't reproduce your problem. I just tried it with Qt 5.5, running the above code with `qmlscene` after changing the import to QtQuick 2.3. Worked fine.

Comment: The problem was that i tried this in the `Window`scope. There, childrenRect is not defined.

Comment: Ah, indeed, because `Window` is not an `Item`. So I guess you'd need to use an explicit root item that is a child of the window.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the `width` and `height` manually works, but is a little ugly:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "gray"
    width: label.width+20
    height: label.height+20
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `chilrenRect` property is sufficient (as suggested by Thorbjørn Lindeijer). It doesn't automatically take into account all various margins of the child(ren) element(s). If the latter changes, the root rectangle doesn't automatically adjust its size. I personally came with the following solution:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "white"
    implicitWidth: row.implicitWidth + extraLeft + extraRight
    implicitHeight: row.implicitHeight + extraTop + extraBottom
    
    property int extraMargin: row.anchors.margins ? row.anchors.margins : 0
    property int extraTop: row.anchors.topMargin ? row.anchors.topMargin : extraMargin
    property int extraBottom: row.anchors.bottomMargin ? row.anchors.bottomMargin : extraMargin
    property int extraLeft: row.anchors.leftMargin ? row.anchors.leftMargin : extraMargin
    property int extraRight: row.anchors.rightMargin ? row.anchors.rightMargin : extraMargin
    
    
    RowLayout {
        id: row
        spacing: 50
        anchors.fill:parent
        anchors.margins: 50
        anchors.leftMargin: 100
        
        Label {
            text: "hello"
        }
        Label {
            text: "world"
        }
    }
}
```